# concatenate variables in ansible to pass them as helm flags for deployments

Tags: loops, ansible, kubernetes-helm

The goal is to pass variables from ansible to `helm --set key=value`. The following output structure for ansible is available

```yaml
apps:
- name: proxy
  properties:
  - key: proxy.externalIP
    value: 192.168.178.1
  - key: proxy.service.Type
    value: LoadBalancer
- name: proxylived
  properties:
  - key: proxylived.externalIP
    value: 192.168.178.1
  - key: proxylived.port
    value: 31443
```

The ansible role should execute the following commands

```sh
$ helm install proxy . --set proxy.externalIP=192.168.178.1 --set proxy.service.Type=LoadBalancer 
$ helm install proxylived . --set proxy.externalIP=192.168.178.1 --set proxylived.port=31443
```

My problem is, I don't know how to iterate over the objects. I tried the following:

##### main.yml

```yaml
---
- name: deploy applications
  include_tasks: apps.yml
  loop: "{{ apps }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: app
```

##### apps.yml

```yaml
---
- name: deploy application {{ app.name }}
  ansible.builtin.command:
    argv:
    - /usr/bin/helm
    - install
    - {{ app.name }}
    - {{ how to pass here a list of the key value attributes? }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell and *not* thoroughly tested:

**`apps.yml`**

```yaml
---
- name: create the list of values to set
  set_fact:
    kvs: "{{ kvs | default([]) + ['--set', item.key ~ '=' ~ item.value] }}"
  loop: "{{ app.properties }}"

- name: deploy application {{ app.name }}
  vars:
    base_cmd:
      - "/usr/bin/helm"
      - "install"
      - "{{ app.name }}"
      - "."
  ansible.builtin.command:
    argv: "{{ base_cmd + kvs }}"
```